# Why am I not getting "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" as part of prompt window in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When run the same on Microsoft edge I am able to see it.
What do I need to change in the settings of Chrome browser?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK2Eb.png)

[image]

This is my code:

```
alert("Hello from the JS file");
var age;
var ageroot;

age=prompt("Enter your age");
```

Comment: Please do not downvote, I have not found on Goggle. I have even posted the question on udemy forum and FB javascript groups.I hope this is not mistaken for he questions where people actually check the  "prevent this page....." and then have problems this not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been mentioned here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/drS39waj6ik;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/Prevent$20this$20page$20from$20creating$20additional$20dialogs

And a bug is reported for the same: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721138

Answer (score 0):

Alert and Prompt boxes have native implementation on every browser, and are not customizable by using JavaScript or CSS.

So, Chrome doesn't have this checkbox in its implementation, while Edge has it. Also, it is completely in the hand of the browser to prevent such boxes in future.

Comment: Hi I wrote this as I looked at the instructions video. The instructor was using Chrome from what I know and it was appearing in the video

Comment: @Meenohara -- Chrome also has this checkbox on the alert boxes, AFAIK. But it only gets visible if the page tries to load the alert 2-3 times continuously.

Comment: What I have posted is "prompt" for Microsft edge where it says "Don't let this page create more messages" with check box. I did notice that for the first alert did not show this and I understood
The same prompt is not showing the checkbox and message for chrome even when multiple dialogs are getting created